# What programs can display a sample accurate audio spectrogram?

Tags: math, audio, data-analysis, scientific-computing

What programs can do a sample accurate spectrogram?

A spectrogram is a division of many frequencies of an audio file through time. Almost all programs use FFT that devides sound into segments, say 64 samples, and the result is imprecise.

Please recommend a program that does the most precise audio analysis, i.e a pixel for every sample, i.e maximum 44100 pixels long for one second of sound and say 200/2000 frequency bands.

[image]

Comment: For the moment i have found a program called Sonogram 4 and one that is available by demand from http://www.oae.it/old/guest_editorials/2001/editorial3b.html although the second seems to be more downsampled